# Is it possible to route tickets to a specific group depending on form chosen by end-user with Zendesk?

Tags: zendesk

: Is there a way to have tickets submitted to a specific group (not individual) depending on the form the end-user chooses at the help center?

For instance if the end-user was to choose form A, (out of possible forms A, B, and C) would it be possible on submit, for the ticket to be automatically routed to fall under a specific group in which the task could then be delegated to a specific agent? While forms B and C would route their tickets to their own respective groups?

Is this possible, or does an agent/manager/admin HAVE to assign a ticket to a group manually through the webapp?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED THE ISSUE: This is possible by using triggers.[image: trigger screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I would replace the ticket is new with ticket is created so it will do that routing once on ticket creation.